# Order query on count and fetch name by id in other table

Tags: mysql, count

I have two tables, one called fruits with:

```
id title

1  Banana
2  Apple
3  Orange
```

And a second fruits_chosen:

```
   user_id  fruit_id

   1        1
   2        1
   2        3 
   3        1
   3        2
   3        3
```

It should return:

```
 Banana 3 times
 Orange 2 times
 Apple  1 time
```

Now I build a query which fetch the items, orders them by count, but I don't know how I can fetch the title from the other table in the same query, any ideas?

```
"SELECT COUNT(fruit_id) as count, fruit_id FROM fruits_chosen GROUP BY fruit_id ORDER BY COUNT(fruit_id) DESC LIMIT 5"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT 
COUNT(*) as count,
f.title, 
fruit_id 
FROM fruits_chosen fc
INNER JOIN fruits f on f.id = fc.fruit_id
GROUP BY 
fc.fruit_id, f.title
ORDER BY count DESC 
LIMIT 5
```

[SqlFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fad14/3)

Answer (score 2):

You will want to `JOIN` the tables using the `fruit_id` to `id` column, similar to this:

```
SELECT f.title, 
    COUNT(fc.fruit_id) as count
FROM fruits_chosen fc
INNER JOIN fruits f
    on fc.fruit_id = f.id
GROUP BY f.title
ORDER BY COUNT(fc.fruit_id) DESC LIMIT 5
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fad14/5)

This is using an `INNER JOIN` which will return only those rows that are matching in both tables.  If you want to return all `fruits` regardless of whether or not it was picked, then you could use a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT f.title, 
    COUNT(fc.fruit_id) as count
FROM fruits f
LEFT JOIN fruits_chosen fc
    on fc.fruit_id = f.id
GROUP BY f.title
ORDER BY COUNT(fc.fruit_id) DESC LIMIT 5
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b3eb2/1)

If you then wanted it to return `Banana 3 times`, etc, you can use the `CONCAT` function in MySQL:

```
SELECT 
  concat(f.title, ' ',COUNT(fc.fruit_id), ' times') Total
FROM fruits f
LEFT JOIN fruits_chosen fc
    on fc.fruit_id = f.id
GROUP BY f.title
ORDER BY COUNT(fc.fruit_id) DESC LIMIT 5
```

See [SQL Fiddle with Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/b3eb2/2)

Comment: Thanks @bluefeet, for you elaborated answer, easy to understand the way you explain it! :)